# Difference between ODBC and Python DB-API?

Tags: database, odbc, python-db-api

Well, I tried to understand **Open Database Connectivity** and **Python DB-API**, but I can't.

ODBC is some kind of standard and Python DB-API is another standard, but why not use just one standard? Or maybe I got these terms wrong.

Can someone please explain these terms and the difference between them as some of the explanations I read were too technical?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are other programming languages besides python -- java, javascript, ruby, perl, cobol, lisp, smalltalk, go, r, and many, many others. None of them can use the python db-api, but all of them could, potentially use odbc. Python offers odbc for people who come from other languages and already know odbc, and its own db-api for people who only know python and who aren't interested in learning the standard. Also, python db-api isn't really a standard, because it hasn't been accepted by any standards body (afaik)